# chunk running time and knit running time question

Tags: r, knitr, chunked-encoding

I got the following code.

```
library(gbm)
library(magrittr)

mydata = read.csv(file="optometry_student.csv",header=T,sep=",")
set.seed(24)
mycombinations = expand.grid(shrinkage=c(0.001,0.01,0.1),interaction.depth=c(3,6,9),bag.fraction=c(0.5,0.5,0.5),optimal_trees=0,min_deviance=0)
for(i in 1:nrow(mycombinations)) {
  set.seed(24)
  bagging_m <- gbm(
    formula = tabxneg0~.,
    distribution="bernoulli",
    data = mydata,
    n.trees = 500,
    interaction.depth = mycombinations$interaction.depth[i],
    shrinkage = mycombinations$shrinkage[i],
    bag.fraction = mycombinations$bag.fraction[i],
    cv = 5
  )
  mycombinations$optimal_trees[i] <- which.min(bagging_m$cv.error)
  mycombinations$min_deviance <-min(bagging_m$cv.error)
}
mycombinations %>%
  dplyr::arrange(min_deviance) %>%
  head(5)
```

and when I run this code first time, it took approximately 2 minutes to finish.However, when I knit this to pdf, it was always at the status of running, couldn't get the output

And also, when I tried to run this chunk at second time, it also couldn't get finished.

Anyone knows what causes the difference between running time of same code?

Comment: Are you able to post the entire `.rnw` file?